# Closure for a mixed metric function

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ |x|\leq 2 \}$$
$$B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ 0< x+y < 2 \}$$

and

$$C=A\cap B$$

One can define the following metric $d:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, by the rule
$$d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=|x_1-y_1|+d_0(x_2,y_2)$$
where $d_0$ stands for the discrete metric defined as $d_0(x, y) = 0$ if $x = y$ and $d_0(x, y) = 1$ otherwise.

> The question asks for describing the closure of set $C$ under metric
>   $d$ defined above.

Here is my attempt understanding this problem:

First question that I asked myself is 'how I can simplify $d$?'

One can write $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=|x_1-y_1|$ if $x_2=y_2$, and $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=|x_1-y_1|+1$ otherwise. Next, I asked 'how can I describe an closed ball of such metric?'
So, if $(q_1,q_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $r=0$, then $B_d[(q_1,q_2),r]=(q_1,q_2)$. Next, suppose that $r>0$. And then, 
$$B_d[(q_1,q_2),r]=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:d((q_1,q_2),(x_1,x_2))\leq r\}$$
which is
$$\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x_1-q_1|+d_0(x_2,q_2)\leq r\}$$,
so, if $x_2=q_2$, then $d_0(q_2,x_2)=0$ and we have
$$\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x_1-q_1|\leq r\}=[q_1-r,q_1+r]\times\{q_2\}.$$

But if $x_2\neq q_2$, then  $d_0(q_2,x_2)=1$ and

$$\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x_2\neq q_2 \ and \ |x_1-q_1|+d_0(x_2,q_2)\leq r\}$$,

which is

$$\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x_2\neq q_2 \ and \ |x_1-q_1|\leq r-1\}$$,

so

if $r<1$ we have $B_d[(q_1,q_2),r]=\emptyset$, while if $r\geq 1$ then

$$[q_1-(r-1),q_2+(r-1)]\times (\mathbb{R}-\{q_2\}$$

> How I can proceed from here, or perhaps there is a different way,
>   describing the closure of $C$ under $d$?

Comment: Just a note, you contradicted yourself by saying that the closed ball would be the empty set if $r < 1$, because when $r = 0 < 1$, we have the closed ball around $(q_1, q_2)$ being $\{(q_1, q_2)\}$ itself.  When $r < 1$, the closed ball should just be $[q_1 - r, q_1 + r] \times \{q_2\}$.

Comment: You can simplify d by tossing it out and dealing directly with the product topology R×Rd where R is the usual space of reals and Rd is the discrete space of reals.

Comment: Use the fact that (x-r, x+r)×{y}, 0 < r is an open nhood of (x,y) and skip all that tedious metric stuff.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Could you please explain how is your observation can reveal closure of the given set, $C$?

Comment: I have described a base for R×Rd.  Use that with the fact that x is in the closure of A iff for all base sets U, (x in U implies U intersection A is not empty).